# ConfigMap having a an Array of db names as data

Tags: kubernetes

Friends

Im writing a configMap containing an array of postgres db names. Approach 1 throws an error like
scalar value is expected at postgres.db.name

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: postgres-init
data:
  postgres.host: "postgreshost"
  postgres.db.name: {"postgredb1","postgredb1", "postgredb3"}
```

Here is Approach 2 ie postgres.db.name having db names separated by comma

```
----
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: postgres-init
data:
  postgres.host: postgreshost
  postgres.db.name: postgredb1,postgredb1,postgredb3
```

Which is the correct way to achieve db names as an array ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edit: As @ShawnFumo and @HuBeZa pointed out, my old answer was incorrect. Configmap data key/value pairs expect the value to be in string format, therefore it isn't possible to provide a dict/list as value.

note: you have 4 "-" at the start of your second example, which would make the YAML document invalid. new YAML docs start with 3 "-". :)

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: postgres-init
data:
  postgres.host: postgreshost
  # Note the "|" after the key - this indicates a multiline string in YAML, 
  # hence we provide the values as strings.
  postgres.db.name: |
    - postgredb1
    - postgredb2
    - postgredb3
```

Comment: Are there any docs that confirm this? I did a search and can't seem to find anything but this post that specifically says Kubernetes ConfigMap supports an array of information in a particular data item. How would it then be used in a deployment file?

Comment: ConfigMap does not support any type but string. See kubectl apply error: "invalid type for io.k8s.api.core.v1.ConfigMap.data: got "array", expected "string"

Comment: guys, i think you missed the point, but I probably just explained it poorly.

the intention was never to state that a configmap can take arrays at any random point, but in the data.postgres.db.name key as value. this is what the question was asked about, and hence my answer was tailored to it. apologies if it caused confusion.

configmaps always take a key/value pair, and the key has to be a string (as shown by @HuBeZa error message) but the value can be a dict, array, ...

Comment: @OlGe both formats you've suggested will fail. If you want to use a multiline string you need to add a pipe | between the key and the value: `postgres.db.name:  |`

Comment: @HuBeZa true, my mistake, thanks for pointing that out! :D I've edited the answer accordingly.